# Ctrl + C not working in all applications on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: ubuntu, keyboard, system

A cuda process has seemed to fail, so I rebooted my Ubuntu 20.04.

After rebooting, the cuda process began to run well. But I found my Ctrl + C not working in any application. In terminal, it can't stop a process. In Chrome or VSCode, it can't copy.

Any other keys like Ctrl + X and Ctrl + V still work. There is not any other abnormal things. For any other account on Ubuntu, and on Windows, Ctrl + C also works, so it is not a hardware issue.

In addition, when I press Ctrl + C, I can't switch between windows for a few tenths of seconds, and all processes in all terminals stop displaying during this time. So is it in the `top` program. And I can see  `Xorg` takes almost all CPU for a few seconds in the `top` program after the stop.

And if I add a keyboard shortcut of Ctrl + C in Ubuntu settings GUI, this shortcut will work fine, there won't be a stop or something.

I have tried uninstalling inputting method; sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade; rebooting. These didn't work.